# Bug de execução jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou com um probleminha bem estranho, nunca tinha me deparado com ele.

...

```
function resizeResponsivo() {
    var 
    width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;

    if ( width < 651 && keys[0]) {
        keys[0] = false;
        keys[2] = true;
        //
        $(menuBlockB).css('float','left');
        resizeResponsivo(); 
    //
    } else if (width < 493 && keys[1]) {
        keys[1] = false;
        keys[3] = true;
        //
        $(forumBoxLast).hide(function() {
```

...

Quando o usuário entra no site, eu executo a função para ajustar o template na pagina, ele executa a primeira condição, na segunda ele para, mas se eu colocar um alert(); em ambas funções ele executa normalmente.  Exemplo:

```
if ( width < 651 && keys[0]) {
    alert();
...
else if ( width < 493 && keys[1] ) {
    alert();
```

Como posso reparar esse erro?

Conteúdo resolvido, coloquei a função dentro de um setTimeout() e funcionou :)

Comment: Deve ter sido um deadlock mesmo... com a chamada assíncrona isso não acontece.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito um problema que deve ser solucionado primeiro são as variáveis globais
como `menuBlockB`.
Você tem que verificar como testa o seu onload do jQuery.
Verifica também a ordem que os seus arquivos estão executando.

Mas acredito que pode ser um problema voltado a `onload`.

Answer (score -1):

Jogando a sua função para execução pós o `document.ready(function(){})` resolveria o problema já que as funções do .window da DOM já foram carregadas com os parâmetros da tela.